# Can I use a ground instead of a dedicated C wire for a thermostat

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

My new wi-fi thermostat requires a common wire coming from the 24 volt transformer. Rather than running an additional wire can I ground the common side of the transformer to the building steel ( this is a commercial application) and pick it up at the thermostat 100 feet away?

Comment: As @Tester101 answers - it seems like you're confusing "grounding" with actually running current through the walls of the building.  That works in cars, but not in a building.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you do as you propose, you'd be using the structure of the building as a current carrying conductor.  This is not allowed by any building code that I'm familiar with.